# UVA and UVB radiations every hour over a year in a given city

Tags: data-request, medical, weather, climate

I'm looking for a dataset that contains how much UVA and UVB radiations a given city received every hour over a year.

E.g.:

- 0.0 kJ/m² UVA and 0.0 kJ m² UVB between 00 and 01 AM on 2020-01-01 in Seattle.
- 0.0 kJ/m² UVA and 0.0 kJ m² UVB between 01 and 02 AM on 2020-01-01 in Seattle.
- [...]
- 0.3 kJ/m² UVA and 0.0 kJ m² UVB between 08 and 09 AM on 2020-01-01 in Seattle.
- 0.9 kJ/m² UVA and 0.1 kJ m² UVB between 09 and 10 AM on 2020-01-01 in Seattle.
- 1.2 kJ/m² UVA and 0.3 kJ m² UVB between 10 and 11 AM on 2020-01-01 in Seattle.
- etc.

Preference if values are averaged over several years. Also, the finer the wavelength ranges, the better: e.g., instead of having UVA = [315 nm; 400 nm] and UVB = [280 nm; 315 nm], measurements could be move fine-grained, such as range_1 = [315 nm; 330 nm], range_2 = [330 nm; 345 nm]; etc. I'd also be interested in UVC ([100 nm; 280 nm]).

I am not interested in the [UV index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_index) because it is erythemally weighted UV: I want the UVA and UVB breakdown.